# Statistics - Correlation and Graphing

Tags: statistics, correlation

A slide with that has a total of five correlation graphs.  The question asks to "Study the plots above and match each graph with the best value of the Pearson correlation."
There are graphs A, B, C, D, E

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCJad.jpg]

```
The provided numbers are:
```

r = +0.82

r = 0.00

r = -0.92

r = +0.66

r = -0.76

I had thought about the provided numbers and came to the conclusion that:

Graph A = r 0.00

The others I am confused on, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: B and E have positive correlation, C and D negative. The less the scatter about the line, the larger the absolute value of $r.$ See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) for labeled examples.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at how scattered the points are. If they are closed to each other and on the line, this indicates strong correlation i.e. close to -1 and 1 (negative and positive depend on the trend of your data points). Otherwise, the correlation will be moderate or weak, again, depends on how scattered and how non-linear the trends are.

In this case,
A, r = 0.
B, r = 0.82.
C, r = -0.92.
D, r = -0.76.
E, r = 0.66.

Note that correlation tells how strong the linear relationship between the explanatory and response variables. Hence, you can have the case which data points are very closed to each other but does not form a linear trend (e.g. parabola), you will have r closed to 0.

Next time, please at least provide your guess and some reasonings on other graphs.